# problems with man pages

Tags: command-line, manpage

after trying to install man pages in italian language I get this error:

```
man ls
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz: No such file or directory
No manual entry for ls
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Actually I deleted the man* folders in `/usr/shar/man/`. How can I solve? I don't want the italian pages, just fix this error

**EDIT**

After a reboot, the folders has appeared again, but inside there aren't .gz files, there are files like:

```
file.[1-9]
```

where the numbers are the same of the folder man[1-9]

Comment: Does `man ls` work now?

Comment: no, nothing work. I have some folders in Italian, bur there are few command. I want the default  folders, where can I find them?

Answer (score 3):

First reinstall the `man-db` package, which contains the basic manual infrastructure

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall man-db
```

Then if an individual man page is missing, reinstall the package of the program in question, which should also contain the man pages. For `ls`, the package is `coreutils`.

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked. But can you expand on why this might happen and a way to avoid it without having to reinstall packages.

Comment: @Passerby Just don't `rm` the man pages...